# How many words with 4 different consonants and 3 different syllables can be created if we have 9 consonants and 6 syllables available such that...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

We have $9$ different consonants and $6$ different vowels available. How many words (not necessarily actual words) can be created using $4$ different consonants and $3$ different vowels such that no two vowels stands next to each other?

Here's what I've got so far:

The number of words with 4 different consonants and 3 different vowels is $\binom{9}{4}.\binom{6}{3}.7!$

To solve for the case where we don't want any two vowels next to each other, we want to put every vowel between at least two consonants.

First we choose our $4$ consonants and shuffle them. That can be done in $\binom{9}{4}.4!$ ways.

Let's labels our consonants $C$. Then there are $5$ gaps (labeled $X$) where we can potentially place our vowel.

(X **C** X **C** X **C** X **C** X)

Choosing $3$ gaps out of $5$ and choosing $3$ consonants out of $6$ + shuffling them can be done in $\binom{5}{3}.\binom{6}{3}.3!$ ways.

Hence the answer to the question is:

$\binom{9}{4}.\binom{5}{3}.\binom{6}{3}.4!3!$

Could that be a correct approach? I've considered using principle of exclusion and inclusion but I couldn't figure iut what would the sets themselves represent.

Comment: By "6 different syllables" do you mean 6 different vowels?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. A typo. I'm going to edit it right now

Comment: @RobertMurray, fixed the typo

Comment: @runtotherescue I didnt realize that no two vowels can be next to each other statement, so your answer is correct

Comment: I think your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is a sort of confirmation.

If we only discern the letters on base of split up "consonant/vowel" then we can approach the problem by means of stars and bars where the vowels serve as bars and the consonants as stars.

To be found is then the number of quadruples $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3)$ where the $c_i$ are nonnegative integers satisfying the extra conditions $c_0+c_1+c_2+c_3=4$ (number of selected consonants) and $c_1,c_2>0$ (the vowels are not allowed to be consecutive).

There are $\binom53$ such quadruples.

Discerning the vowels and their order we must multiply with $6P3$.

Discerning the consonants and their order we must multiply with $9P4$.

So the final answer is $$\binom53\times6P3\times9P4$$
This agrees with your own result.